# pythonで線構造の抽出

Tags: python, 画像

写真のように、点の集合の中からデータと思われる部分（線構造っぽいところ）を抜き出したいと考えています。
オープニング処理などを試しましたが、線が途切れているところが周りのノイズとうまく判別できませんでした。
アドバイスいただきたいです。

[image: 点の集合]

Comment: [How to detect lines in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv) に対する[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560545)が参考になるかと思います。